# Apache - Permissions are missing on a component of the path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, permissions, chmod, chown

None of my website images are loaded, although paths are correct. In my Apache logs, I have plenty of :

```
(13)Permission denied: [client 87.231.108.18:57108] AH00035: access to 
my/file/path/some-photo.jpg denied because search permissions are missing 
on a component of the path
```

Within `httpd.conf` file :

```
User apache
Group apache
```

All the way down to my website directory, folders are owned by `apache:apache`, with `chmod` set to `774` all the way down.

SELinux boolean `httpd_can_network_connect` has been is `On`.

I am using a `.htaccess` file to redirect my domain name to the appropriate directory. I suspect this might be cause the issue but... this is nothing more than a gut feeling.

I do need help, any suggestion is most welcomed. 
Many thanks!

**EDIT**
Content of the .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.domain\.com
RewriteRule (.*) /domain/$1 [L]
```

Comment: In that case, could you show your htaccess code ?

Comment: Right UP! 
Thanks for the help proposition

Comment: Your images are in `domain` folder ?

Comment: It is a Wordpress website. Images are in `domain/wp-content/uploads`

Comment: That's weird, your htaccess code does not look like a Wordpress one. Anyway, i guess you access your images with `www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/image.jpg` ?

Comment: That .htaccess file isn't the one of Wordpress, but the one of the `/var/www/html` folder to redirect domain name to folders on the server. 

To answer your question : YES, that is the way images are called within the website

Comment: Did you add some rules or something else in Wordpress htaccess ?

Comment: That is a good one. Let me check

Comment: You put me on the right track sir. Thanks a ton.
You ended a long wandering. I'll answer my own question providing the details of my fix

Comment: A quick check to determine if it is related to SELinux is (1) see if SELinux is enabled using the sestatus command to see if it reports 'enforcing'. If the status reports disabled or 'permissive', then SELinux isn't the cause.   If it is 'enforcing', run % setenforce Permissive (and verify with sestatus that it is, indeed, running 'permissive'), restart your httpd, and see if you now are able to access the resource.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I finally found it! Thanks a ton Justin lurman to poiting out the .htaccess file. It made me see that Wordpress didn't have the right to edit my .htaccess file anymore. 
That was even more weird because I was 100% sure that permissions were good (even way too permissive if you ask me).

So I looked into SElinux, as I know it can play tricks on me at times and I was right. 
Issuing the following command solved it :

```
chcon -R --type=httpd_sys_rw_content_t wp-content/
```

I hope that helps someone else :)

Comment: Thanks, it helps on CentOS 7

Comment: This kicked my butt for a couple hours. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, it helps on Fedora 36

Answer (score 13):

In my case the containing folder did not have the +x permission, changing it to 755 did the trick.

Answer (score 9):

What worked for me was that all component directories in the path needed execute permissions for all

so if the path of the website is /home/user1/public_html/docroot

```
chmod +x /home/user1/
chmod +x /home/user1/public_html/
chmod +x /home/user1/public_html/docroot/
```

Comment: For me it was the right solution, tnx.

Answer (score 4):

Or you can run

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

In those folders...

Answer (score 4):

```
setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs 1

chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t /home/user/public_html
```

Comment: I was getting the exact error in the OP, despite the search permissions, both chmod and SELinux chcon, set properly on every component of the path. Spent hours, constantly finding the same answers to set permissions on the path components using chmod and chcon. Without an explanation on this answer, I would've likely skipped it as not addressing the path components issue in the error message, if I hadn't been so desperate for something different. Despite the error message pointing to those path components, it turned out that setting the SELinux option httpd_enable_homedirs resolved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

On macOS it might be caused by a user group permission issue.

Go to `httpd.conf` file (located at `/usr/local/etc/httpd` if Apache is installed by Homebrew). Find `<IfModule unixd_module>` and change the value in front of `User` to your computer username (that you log in with). Restart Apache.

This needs to be done to PHP-FMP as well if you are using that with Apache.
Find `php-fpm.conf` file (usually located at `/usr/local/etc/php/7.x/` and find the pool definitions:

uncomment `include=/usr/local/etc/php/7.x/php-fpm.d/*.conf` if commented and save the file. now open the recently uncommented file and find `user =` and change the value of user to your computer username. Now restart PHP service.

Answer (score 1):

Just one command:

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_enable_homedirs 1
```

Helps for me.

Comment: Already [metioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43053662/6670491). Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you and marking helpful answer.